# SPSS - Round down to 4th decimal

Tags: rounding, spss, truncate

I have a variable, Weight, with values at 5 decimals places. e.g., `1.00005, 2.67549, .21425` etc.

I'm simply trying to round them DOWN to four decimal places, so:

```
1.00005 --> 1.0000
2.67549 --> 2.6754
.21425 --> .2142
1.43640 --> 1.4364
```

I need the actual values, not just their formatting/presentation, to be changed this way.

ROUND won't work, because that rounds up, and TRUNC rounds down to the nearest whole integer (or variation of that integer). Is there a simple command or argument to do this? Something like Excel's ROUNDDOWN function would be magical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the function you want:

```
compute RoundVar=trunc(OrigVar,0.0001).
```

This would also do it:

```
compute RoundVar=trunc(OrigVar*10000)/10000.
```